# The name 'txtStudentDOB' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Web form user control and I want to add a calender to a textbox in edit form, but I get this error for **txtStudentDOB** in **void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)** . the problem is I cannot access to calender from the edit form context.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

namespace LearningSystem.Controls
{
 public partial class usrStudent : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = false;
        }

    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Calendar1.Visible == false)
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Calendar1.Visible = true;
        }
    }

     void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStudentDOB.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
    }
 }
```

**here is HTML codes**

```
 <asp:FormView ID="frmStudent" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsStudent" Width="100%" OnItemDeleted="frmStudent_ItemDeleted" DataKeyNames="StudentID" OnItemInserted="frmStudent_ItemInserted" OnItemUpdated="frmStudent_ItemUpdated" >
<EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentDOB" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("StudentDOB" , "{0:d}") %>'  />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtStudentDOB" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Date of Birth" ForeColor="Red">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RangeValidator ID ="rvDate" runat ="server" C
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10"">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" Font-Bold="false" />
    </div>
    </div>
</EditItemTemplate>

<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged1" >          </asp:Calendar>
```

Comment: Why is the calendar outside of the `EditItemTemplate`? If it was inside you could do: `TextBox = txtStudentDOB = (TextBox)((FormViewItem)((Calendar)sender).NamingContainer).FindControl("txtStudentDOB")`

Comment: it doesn't matter. when I put it Inside I get error again which says "The name 'Calendar1' does not exist in the current context", but when I put it outside I get this error for textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access the control within a formview directly. You need to find it in the form view. Try the following code

```
void Calendar1_SelectionChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TextBox txtStudentDOB = frmStudent.FindControl("txtStudentDOB") as TextBox;
   if(txtStudentDOB != null)
   {
      txtStudentDOB.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
      Calendar1.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: When I select a date from calender it cannot be shown in textbox and I get this error **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** in this line :            **txtStudentDOB1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();**

Comment: is txtStudentDOB1 null or Calendar1 null or Calendar1.SelectedDate?

Comment: Can you check the name txtStudentDOB matches in the designer and in the FindControl function?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, thats right, tx for pointing, the textbox is only in edit template. Of course need to check null

Comment: It is completely match.

Comment: @user2083099, I have updated the code. You need to check txtStudentDOB for null. Note that the control is available only in the EditMode, but your calendar control is outside the EditItemTemplate. So if the form is not in edit mode, then if you select a date in calendar control, the textbox will be null.

Comment: I dont get any error but the value of the date cannot pass to the textbox and remain like before.